# How to invoke a post drush command?

Tags: 8, drush

I am using Drush 9 and Drupal 8. When I execute `drush site:install` I find that it also modifies the permission of the web/site/default directory to r-xr-x--x, which troubles me delete that directory later. I want that directory to be 740 in my case. So two methods came to my mind. One is to run a custom shell script as post `drush si` or to override the default `dush si` command. I tried to go through some blogs but I couldn't understand them. Please explain stepwise.

How can I invoke a custom shell script to `drush site:install` which will be run just after that command is executed.

How can I override the default `site:install` command?

Note: I am using [Drupal composer project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project). So I have a [drush folder](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/tree/8.x/drush) outside the webroot but I don't know if I can edit some files in that directory and write my custom commands.

Comment: Every time the cache is cleared in Drupal and some other similar events, it will lock those folders down.

Comment: So you mean it is not only matter of `drush si` but any command  is executed it will modify the permission. Any way to provide my custom permission ?

Comment: @Kevin I examined with drush cr and cc. But It doesn't modify the permission. Only drush si does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Greg's answer is great. But to more precisely answer this particular question follow the below steps.

1- As you are using Drupal composer project template, Go to the directory `your_drupal_project/drush` and create a file called `SiteInstallCommands.php`. You can see there are another similar file `PolicyCommands.php`.

2- **SiteInstallCommands.php** should have below code snippets. `installTest()` is your custom commands that is going to be executed post site:install. So change it according to your needs.

```
<?php

namespace Drush\Commands;


class SiteInstallCommands extends DrushCommands
{

    /**
     * Executing command just after `drush site:install`
     *
     * @hook post-command site-install
     *
     */
    public function installTest() {
        drush_shell_exec('echo test');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

See the example file [PolicyCommands.php](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/Commands/PolicyCommands.php) in the Druhs examples directory. Create a directory named "Commands" in your site's "drush" directory, and put your command file there. Its name must end with "Commands.php" or "Hooks.php".

Create a hook similar to one of the ones shown in the example file. You'll want `@hook post-command site:install`.

Comment: Thanks. Do I also need to define drush.yml here https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/tree/8.x/drush ? Is there anything I need to define or edit ? Can you please have a look on this link ?

Comment: For testing purpose, as per the documentation I run `drush --include=/var/www/drupal/vendor/drush/drush/examples xkcd` , `drush cc drush`, then `drush xkcd`, but getting error command is not defined. Am I missing something ?

Comment: If you put your command in /var/www/drupal/drush/Commands, then you do not need `--include`

Answer (score 0):

To create a site:install hook I just needed to create a file SiteInstallCommands.php inside [drush/Commands](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/tree/8.x/drush/Commands) dir. then `drush cc drush` to clear the drush cache and my custom post command is up. Thanks to @greg_1_anderson for guiding. Note you have to add **`@hook post-command site-install`** not `@hook post site:install`.

```
<?php

namespace Drush\Commands;


class InstallCommands extends DrushCommands
{

    /**
     * Modify files/directory permission as per project's need executing just after `drush site:install`
     *
     * @hook post-command site-install
     *
     */
    public function installChmod() {
        $this->logger()->success(dt('Executing post site:install commands'));
        drush_shell_exec('chmod -R 740 sites/default');

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting my typo; I fixed my answer to "post-command"