# How can I use "drush updb" to pass a value to the hook_update_N() implementation done from a module?

Tags: hooks, drush, 9

I am trying to `drush updb` with an argument that is passed to the `hook_update_N()` implementation done from a module I wrote, which would use it to execute some update tasks.

```php
function my_module_update_9001(&$value) {
  switch ($value) {
    case "unique":
      _set_unique_identifier();
      break;

    case "get":
      _get_field_typ_map();
      break;

    default:
      echo "Something went wrong...";
  }
}

function _set_unique_identifier() {
  _get_database_shame_connector()->uniqueIdentifier();
}
    
function _get_field_typ_map() {
  _get_database_shame_connector()->getFieldTypeMap();
}
```

How do I tell `drush updb` to pass an argument to an `hook_update_N()`  implementation?

Comment: Not really clear what you're trying to do/want to do.

Comment: Update hooks take $sandbox argument which contains information about the running batch. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/9.3.x - i.e. not a callable function you can invoke whenever, and will only run once. updb is not for this type of data manipulation. You need to write an actual Drush command that accepts arguments to build this out.

Comment: Agreed. As written, this is impossible.

Comment: It's also not possible because `drush updb` doesn't accept such parameter; it only accepts four options.

Comment: Updb is the wrong direction. Create your own custom Drush command.

Comment: But with an env var, maybe... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible because [`drush updb`](https://www.drush.org/latest/commands/updatedb/) doesn't accept a parameter that is passed to [`hook_update_N()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_update_N/9.3.x) implementations, which makes sense, since the only parameter accepted from `hook_update_N()` is an array that allows that hook to use [batch operations](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21form.inc/group/batch/9.3.x) to run its updates. Passing a different argument to `hook_update_N()` implementations would cause issues with those implementations that use the batch API to run updates.

Even in the case `drush updb` would accept an argument to pass to an update hook and the function name for a `hook_update_N()` implementation, that implementation should be able to understand whether it's called by Drush with a different argument or by Drupal core with the expected argument.

There is a simpler way to execute code that runs after `drush updb`:  Implement a post-command hook, as described on [How to invoke a post drush command?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/272803/how-to-invoke-a-post-drush-command) for example.

```php
namespace Drush\Commands;

class PostUpdateCommands extends DrushCommands {

  /**
   * Executes commands right after `drush updatedb`.
   *
   * @hook post-command updatedb
   *
   */
  public function postUpdate() {
    // Your code
  }

}
```